# Why webpack add properties to '__webpack_require__' function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm a code beginner and recently I've began to see and try to understand the code and design of some libraries. I've noticed that Webpack, when it creates a bundle, use the '**webpack_require**' function to load needed modules but I don't understand why, after the function definition, it add it properties like:

```js
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
```

Why it add properties to a function instead of create an object? Are there advantages in this practice? Excuse me for beginner's question.
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: There are comments above functions you've posted. I'm using webpack since around 4 years, and I had never to deal with this. They are more or less internal helpers

Comment: I know use Webpack, my question is only for curiosity and personal knowledge.

Comment: The advantage over exporting them as properties of an object is that you can call a function - most likely a vital design requirement for `__webpack_require__`. As for why these are exported at all, despite probably not supposed to be used by user code, we can only guess.

Answer (score -2):

It's simply a container for the imported modules, and is used only inside the bundle. I personally use `source-map` to debug, than reading the uncompressed bundle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm only interested understand how webpack works, not for my bundles but for my curiosity.